# Using prop.test on grouped variables in dataframe

Tags: r

I've got the dataframe below and trying to compute if there is a significant difference in the proportions between the groups within each category. E.g. category A group 1 verus 2, 1 versus 3, and 2 versus 3.

Is there a way to calculate and add the p-values to the dataframe as new columns without having to calculate it and add it manually one row at a time?

Or is there a way to calculate them and store them in a separate data frame?

```
          Group   Category number min total  Proportion
1          1         A      6  2.5    33 0.1818182
2          1         B      4  3.2    33 0.1212121
3          1         C     16  3.2    33 0.4848485
4          1         D      7  3.1    33 0.2121212
5          2         A     22  6.4   133 0.1654135
6          2         B     17  6.7   133 0.1278195
7          2         C     56  6.0   133 0.4210526
8          2         D     38  6.4   133 0.2857143
9          3         A      3 10.0    22 0.1363636
10         3         B      3  9.7    22 0.1363636
11         3         C      9 10.6    22 0.4090909
12         3         D      7  9.9    22 0.3181818
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite complicated although it looks like an easy task. Here is the solution using the `purrr` package as the core tool.

Let's import data:

```
data <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L), Category = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
 "B", "C", "D"), number = c(4L, 16L, 7L, 22L, 17L, 56L, 38L, 3L, 
 3L, 9L, 7L), min = c(3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 6.4, 6.7, 6, 6.4, 10, 9.7, 
 10.6, 9.9), total = c(33L, 33L, 33L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 
 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L), Proportion = c(0.1212121, 0.4848485, 0.2121212, 
 0.1654135, 0.1278195, 0.4210526, 0.2857143, 0.1363636, 0.1363636, 
 0.4090909, 0.3181818)), row.names = 2:12, class = "data.frame")
```

and required packages:

```
library(dplyr) # mutate, group_by and rowwise functions
library(tidyr) # nest
library(purrr) # map
library(combinat) # combn
```

We will create `tibble` object  `foo` which divides original dataset according to groups. That allows us to map function to the groups.

```
foo <- foo %>% mutate(tab = map(data, combFun))
```

Now we define own function `combPval` which 1) creates a data.frame of combinations of factors (`combTab`), 2) creates data.frame `tab1` which stores relevant columns for `prop.test`. These data.frames are merged in subsequent steps to create data.frame `data`. `prop.test` is then applied by in a `rowwise` way.

```
combPval <- function(group){
 combTab <- combn(unique(group$Category), 2) %>% t() %>% data.frame()
 tab1 <- group %>% select(Category, number, total)
 combTab
 temp <- merge(y=combTab, x=tab1, by.y="X2", by.x="Category" ) 
 data <- merge(y=temp, x=tab1, by.y="X1", by.x="Category")

 data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
   pval = prop.test(x=c(number.x, number.y), n=c(total.x, total.y))$p.val
  )

 data
}
```

Function `combPval` is applied in the following way:

```
foo <- foo %>% mutate(results = map(data, combPval))
```

Results for the first group can be obtained:

```
 foo$results[[1]]

 # A tibble: 3 x 7
 # Rowwise: 
   Category number.x total.x Category.y number.y total.y    pval
   <chr>       <int>   <int> <chr>         <int>   <int>   <dbl>
 1 B               4      33 C                16      33 0.00322
 2 B               4      33 D                 7      33 0.509  
 3 C              16      33 D                 7      33 0.0388
```

Comment: Has my answer solved your problem? If so, please consider closing the question by accepting the answer.